# What is the order of execution of OnClick and PointerUp in Unity?

Tags: unity, gui

I have an UI element in Unity with a Button and a Event Trigger component. The Button component calls a method when the OnClick event is triggered, and the Event Trigger component calls another method when the PointerUp event is triggered. I need the OnClick event to be triggerd always after the PointerUp event is triggered. This seems to be the case, but I'm not sure if I can assume this order of execution is what Unity actually uses. Is this the case or Unity uses a random order of execution?

Comment: Can't you test it multiple times to check yourself ? I think if everytime you do it it's in the good order, then it should be the case.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html